# Can't access server from local ip

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, localhost

am using freezer (https://git.freezer.life/exttex/freezerpc) and I can only access the server on localhost :/. I tried editting settings.js and replaced 127.0.0.1 with 0.0.0.0 then built it but it still runs on localhost only. I tried disabling the firewall but nothing.

```
class Settings {

constructor(electron = false) {
    //Defaults
    this.port = 10069;
    this.serverIp = '0.0.0.0';
    this.arl;
    this.streamQuality = 3;
    this.volume = 0.69;
    this.electron = electron;
    this.minimizeToTray = true;
    this.closeOnExit = false;
    this.width = 1280;
    this.height = 720;
```

it has a server.js file which has this:

```
    //Express
const app = express();
app.use(express.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client', 'dist')));
app.use(cors({origin: 'http://localhost:8080'}));
//Server
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const io = new Server(server, {
    path: '/socket',
    //CORS for webpack debug
    cors: {
        origin: 'http://localhost:8080',
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    }
});
```

there's this at the end of the server.js file

```
    //Start server
    let serverIp = override.host ? override.host : settings.serverIp;
    let port = override.port ? override.port: settings.port;
    server.listen(port, serverIp);
    console.log(`Running on: http://${serverIp}:${port}`);

    return settings;
}

module.exports = {createServer};
```

I'm a newbie and I know nothing about is since am  just trying to run the access

Comment: Is this hosted on a public server? or your computer? How are you trying to access the server?

Comment: it's hosted on localhost. when you run the app it runs the server on localhost:10069. am tryna access it using my local ip but I can't. I also tried to "node main.js" but same it only runs on localhost

Comment: Everything ever 'runs on localhost' because it just refers to the computer you are running this on. I'm trying to find out where the script is running, and what machine is trying to access the service. Is it both on the same machine?

Comment: yep it's on the same machine :/

Answer (score 0):

You are never actually starting the server. You need to call `app.listen`

```js
const PORT = 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App is running on port ${PORT}!`);
});
```

Comment: as I said am a BIG newbie sorry. where should I add this?

Comment: You should be able to kill everything below //server and replace with the code I posted.

Comment: it's running on local ip but it's stuck on loading. I also get this after node main.js
https://pastebin.com/6TXe51sd

Comment: //Server
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const io = new Server(server, {
    path: '/socket',
    //CORS for webpack debug
    cors: {
        origin: 'http://localhost:8080',
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    }
});
it already had this below //server @alex collette

Comment: it also has this 

//Start server
    let serverIp = override.host ? override.host : settings.serverIp;
    let port = override.port ? override.port: settings.port;
    server.listen(port, serverIp);
    console.log(`Running on: http://${serverIp}:${port}`);

    return settings;
}

module.exports = {createServer};